# The spin-connection under general coordinate transformation

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, gauge-invariance

How does the spin-connection $\omega_{\mu}^{~~ab}$ transform under general coordinate transformation? Is it a tensor with respect to the $\mu$ index?

Comment: Yes, it is………..

Comment: @PraharMitra Any reference in this regard will be most helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it transforms as a one-form under spacetime GCT's (but it isn't a tensor-valued one form, as you probably know it transforms inhomogeneously for its Lorentz indices).

A good way to check this for yourself is to calculate something like $\nabla_{\mu} T^{a}$ then apply the transformation rules to deduce the the transformation laws for $\omega_{\mu}{}^{a}{}_{b}$.

Comment: Can you provide reference if possible? It will be very helpful.

Comment: @IIRC this sort've calculation is covered in Carrol's GR book https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9712019 (have a look through the parts on the spin connection)

Comment: Thanks that was helpful.